# How to configure retrolambda for android6(API23)

Tags: android, retrolambda

I want to add Java8 support to my project. The only suitable solution I found is retrolambda gradle plugin project. Here is my build.gradle files for a project and module relatively.

*Note: Please don't suggest migrate to Android Studio 3, because I want to understand why it is not working.*

project build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.7.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

module build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.test"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

retrolambda {
    javaVersion JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    defaultMethods true
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

The app itself is pretty simple. It has only one default activity, with Java8 code, like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
        strings.add("Hello");
        strings.add("World");
        strings.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

When start the app I get following an error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                      Process: com.slesh.mtbbank, PID: 25338
>                                                                      java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No interface method
>   stream()Ljava/util/stream/Stream; in class Ljava/util/List; or its
>   super classes (declaration of 'java.util.List' appears in
>   /system/framework/core-libart.jar)
>                                                                          at com.slesh.mtbbank.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
>                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6303)
>                                                                          at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
>                                                                          at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2402)
>                                                                          at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2509)
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:153)
>                                                                          at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373)
>                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5529)
>                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                          at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
>                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)

What is missed? Any ideas why it doesn't work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43027169/how-to-use-jdk-1-8-features-in-all-android#comment73142632_43027169 for some of the available backports that can be used in conjunction with retrolambda.

Comment: whats the use of this `classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.7.0'` ...without this dependency i can convert it into lambda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
strings.stream().forEach(System.out::println)
```

Retrolambda does only what its name suggests: it allows you to use lambdas.   It does not support streams. There are libraries that backport stream API, but retrolambda does not.

Comment: Oh, I thought that it provides support for most Java8 features.